# Elasticsearch order terms aggregate by score

Tags: sorting, search, elasticsearch, aggregation, relevance

I'm new to ElasticSearch. Previously I've used it only with Django-Haystack, in a very limited fashion, and have never talked to ES directly.

Currently, I have an ElasticSearch (5.x if this matters) index with a few documents. I'm using Python + [elasticsearch-dsl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/elasticsearch-dsl) + [django-elasticsearch-dsl](https://github.com/sabricot/django-elasticsearch-dsl) so I'm indexing database models, but it shouldn't really matter. I'll try to leave this question library-agnostic.

Conceptually, I'm storing users, and their posts, all in the same index. The documents for users and for posts have one thing in common - a field `user_id`.

Users look like this:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "_type": "user_document",
    "username": "jdoe",
    "user_id": 1,
    "title": "Test user"
}
```

And posts are like this:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "_doc": "post_document",
    "user_id": 1,
    "title": "Hello world!",
    "text": "Lorem ipsum test test test..."
}
```

What I want my app to implement is a single-input search field that does full-text search over both users and their posts (in real world there are more document "types" - I'm simplifying things here, just for example purposes). And I want to aggregate by `user_id` to show just a list of the distinct users that had matched.

Currently, I'm doing query like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "test",
            "fields": ["username^3", "title^2", "text"]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "user_ids": {"terms": {"field": "user_id"}}
    }
}
```

Then using response's `aggregations.user_ids.buckets.key` to obtain a list of matching users.

However, that list seems to be simply ordered by document count (so if user has a pair of posts with the word "test" they seem to win over the user named "test"), and I want to experiment with ordering. My current idea is to use an average (or a median value) document match `_score`.

Note: in real situation there are more than just two document types, so taking a shortcut and querying just over a specific `_type` won't work.

How can I do this? I'm reading the ["Sorting by a Metric"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_sorting_by_a_metric.html) chapter, but the ideas there are somewhat lost on me. I made a few attempts but they were basically nonsense. Can anyone please show a concrete query example (very much preferably, with explanation how it was constructed), so I can learn from it?

Here is the [Gist with an example dataset](https://gist.github.com/drdaeman/1a4e8e8796deeaf4eabddd72dad0a8c0), the search query shown above, and the exact results I'm getting. What I want (in `test_query_01_results.json`) is to have `user_id` 1 be prioritized over 2, with the logic that 2.0794415 > (0.78306973 + 0.45315093) / 2.

Another thing that I feel I'm doing wrong is that I don't use `hits` at all - I just don't need them - only the aggregated `user_id` values. If this is okay - is there a way to "disable" them and only return aggregations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use following query

```
{
"size": 0 ,                    ==> to return no hits
"query": {                     ==> query similar to yours
    "multi_match": {
        "query": "test",
        "fields": ["username^3", "title^2", "text"]
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "user_ids": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "user_id",
            "order": {"avg_score": "desc"}
        },
        "aggs": {
            "avg_score": {
                "avg": {"script": "_score"}
              }
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

I think I found a solution for sorting the aggregation. I had to create a sub-aggregation, then it all worked. I was mistaken, trying to use `"order": {"_score: "desc"}` and similar nonsense when there wasn't any `_score` there (that's a collection of documents, not a document, so no scores there).

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "test",
            "fields": ["username^3", "title^2", "text"]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "user_ids": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "user_id",
                "order": {"avg_score": "desc"}
            },
            "aggs": {
                "avg_score": {
                    "avg": {"script": "_score"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this my `aggregations` looks just exactly like I wanted:

```
...
"aggregations": {
    "user_ids": {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "avg_score": {"value": 2.079441547393799},
                "doc_count": 1,
                "key": 1
            }, 
            {
                "avg_score": {"value": 0.618110328912735},
                "doc_count": 2,
                "key": 2
            }
        ],
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0
    }
},
...
```

However, the question about having `hits` (that I don't use) still holds.

Answer (score 0):

The answers to the post are great. There is just one little thing to mention.

> Another thing that I feel I'm doing wrong is that I don't use hits at
> all - I just don't need them - only the aggregated user_id values. If
> this is okay - is there a way to "disable" them and only return
> aggregations?

To achieve this, simply use "size": 0 in the "query" field.

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "test",
            "fields": ["username^3", "title^2", "text"]
        }
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "user_ids": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "user_id",
                "order": {"avg_score": "desc"}
            },
            "aggs": {
                "avg_score": {
                    "avg": {"script": "_score"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```